Why does the Shanren Sport Navigation service show 'offline'?
I have a Shanren Discovery Pro bike computer paired to my Google Pixel 6a.
I use the Shanren Sport app from Google Play Store.
The Shanren app has a navigation service which displays directions on the bike computer.
However any attempt to use this displays a message such as  or a toast saying 'offline'. However all other aspects of the app work fine, including displaying my rides on a map (which appears to be Google Maps).
I assume that the app is using some third party navigation service which it cannot reach from my country, or which is out of service.
All permissions are granted.

Further diagnosis shows an attempt to connect to https://api.mapbox.com
App: Shanren Sport (10370)
Protocol: HTTPS (TCP)
SNI: api.mapbox.com
Source: 10.215.173.1:48856
Destination: 18.239.236.44:443
Status: Closed
Country: United Kingdom
ASN: AS16509 - Amazon.com, Inc.
Traffic: 1.4 KB received — 1.2 KB sent
Packets: 8 received — 7 sent
Payload: 2.0 KB
Duration: > 1 m
First seen: 07/24/24 11:20:49.589
Last seen: 07/24/24 11:21:51.371


You could monitor the network connections the app creates, e.g. using PCAPdroid. If you are familiar with Wireshark you could even capture the data and analyze it on a PC. As today most connections use TLS/HTTPS you won't see the content, therefore you can only check the TCP connections established and may be which fails before the error is displayed.

Thanks. It appears that the HTTPS connection goes to api.mapbox.com.

Thanks to @Robert in the comments, I have identified that the app is using the Mapbox API for its navigation service.
It's reasonable to assume that the developers have either exceeded their connection limit or stopped paying for the service.
